# Foreign key constraint »FK_0e4022833a9efc062c01637e552« cannot be implemented - problem with composite primary key?

Tags: sql, postgresql, typeorm

I'm using TypeORM and want to design my database with currently three entities. I created a repository for reproduction

[Github reproduction repository](https://github.com/mhcomp/references-reproduction/tree/master/references-reproduction)

**Update**

I was able to reproduce it with only two small entities

[Very small reproduction repo](https://github.com/mhcomp/small-repro/tree/master/small-repro)

more information to this down below

---

So first of all I have a **module** entity. This one is a small one because it only stores some basic fields.

```
@Entity()
export class Module extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  public id: string;

  // some other fields without references
}
```

Next I have a **graph** entity. This one is holding multiple **graphNodes**. So you can have multiple graphs and each one has its own graphNodes. The graph itself needs to know which graphNode is the first one in the graph. So I tried to setup a foreign key reference to the graphNode entity.

- there can be multiple graphs
- each graph has one graphNode as a starting node
- there are multiple graphNodes per graph

.

```
@Entity()
export class Graph extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  public id: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  public startNodeId?: string;

  @ManyToOne(
    () => GraphNode,
    graphNode => graphNode.id,
  )
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'startNodeId' })
  public startNode: GraphNode;
}
```

The last entity is the **graphNodes** entity. Each graphNode represents a module in one graph. It also knows about its successors *successGraphNodeId* and *errorGraphNodeId*. It's important to node that this entity has a composite primary key because if you want to fetch a graphNode you have to pass in the graph id too. Basically these are the use cases

- a graphNode represents one module
- there are multiple graphNodes per graph
- a graphNode can reference itself as a successor (success/error)
- a graphNode successor can be null (success/error)
- a graphNode successor must be a graphNode that already exists in **this** graph

.

```
@Entity()
export class GraphNode extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  public id: string;

  @PrimaryColumn()
  public graphId: string; // composite key https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/sample/sample27-composite-primary-keys/entity/Post.ts

  @ManyToOne(
    () => Graph,
    graph => graph.id,
  )
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'graphId' })
  public graph: Graph;

  @Column()
  public moduleId: string;

  @ManyToOne(
    () => Module,
    module => module.id,
  )
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'moduleId' })
  public module: Module;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  public successGraphNodeId?: string;

  @ManyToOne(
    () => GraphNode,
    graphNode => graphNode.id,
  )
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'successGraphNodeId' })
  public successGraphNode?: GraphNode;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  public errorGraphNodeId?: string;

  @ManyToOne(
    () => GraphNode,
    graphNode => graphNode.id,
  )
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'errorGraphNodeId' })
  public errorGraphNode?: GraphNode;
}
```

When running the application I'm unfortunately getting this error

```
QueryFailedError: Foreign key constraint »FK_0e4022833a9efc062c01637e552« cannot be implemented
    at new QueryFailedError (...\references-reproduction\node_modules\typeorm\error\QueryFailedError.js:11:28)
    at Query.callback (...\references-reproduction\node_modules\typeorm\driver\postgres\PostgresQueryRunner.js:176:38)
    at Query.handleError (...\references-reproduction\node_modules\pg\lib\query.js:145:17)
    at Connection.connectedErrorMessageHandler (...\references-reproduction\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:214:17)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (...\references-reproduction\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:134:12)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:290:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
```

It seems my entity design is not correct. Does someone know what's wrong or missing here? Please let me know if you need more information or if I should update my reproduction repository.

Thanks in advance

---

**Update**

I was able to reproduce it with two small entities. There only is a relation between a graph

```
@Entity()
export class Graph extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  public id: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  public startNodeId?: string;

  @ManyToOne(
    () => Node,
    node => node.id,
  )
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'startNodeId' })
  public node: Node;
}
```

and its nodes

```
@Entity()
export class Node extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  public id: string;

  @PrimaryColumn()
  public graphId: string;

  @ManyToOne(
    () => Graph,
    graph => graph.id,
  )
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'graphId' })
  public graph: Graph;
}
```

As mentioned before the problem seems to rely on the composite primary key. I don't want to convert the Node's graphId primary column to a basic column because this would be bad database design...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think your problem is on the composite key. For me, your model has several flaws:

- Both `Graph` and `Node` have a `ManyToOne` towards each other. But from what I gather from your explanation, a Node is only attached to a single Graph, so in `Graph`, it should actually be a `OneToMany` representing a list of `Nodes`:

```
@OneToMany(() => Node)
public nodes: Node[];
```

- The second argument of annotation `ManyToOne` is supposed to be the reverse-side attribute, yet you used it to reference the primary key instead. Here is what you should have:

```
class Graph {
  @OneToMany(() => Node, node => node.graph)
  public nodes: Node[];
}

class Node {
  @ManyToOne(() => Graph, graph => graph.nodes)
  public graph: Graph;
}
```

For the `JoinColumn`, typeorm should automatically take what you have specified have primary columns in each entity.

Answer (score 0):

You have two primary keys on GraphNode

```
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
public id: string;

@PrimaryColumn()
public graphId: string;
```

that's why the fk's on self-referenced success- and errorGraphNode won't work.
Remove one PK and work with the other.

Comment: I think this is not the problem. This is a composite key, TypeORM provides an example for those here https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/sample/sample27-composite-primary-keys/entity/Post.ts

Comment: Is there no way to reference a composite key?

Answer (score 0):

You are using foreign key constraint in your entities as:

```
@ManyToOne(
    () => GraphNode,
    graphNode => graphNode.id,
)
```

and respectively in the other entity. You are getting the error because your current database doesn't satisfies this rule. So, the simplest way to get this working is to:

1. Delete current database
2. Create a new database
3. Change configuration to connect to new created database.

Doing this will work all the newly created records would be according to the updated constraints in the database. Hope this works for you.

Comment: I cloned the reproduction repository, deleted the database, created a new one and started the application.  The error still remains ...